# hadoop-2.4.1 fails to build on CentOS-6 x86_64

Tags: java, hadoop, centos6

In my CentOS6 x86_64 I have installed the following packages for building hadoop-2.4.1:

- Maven 3.2.2 (installed from official bin tar ball)
- protobuf 2.5.0 (with compiler, installed from rpms found by rpm.pbone.net)
- Oracle jdk 1.8.0_11 (installed from jdk-8u11-linux-x64.rpm downloaded from oracle website)

  (The following packages are installed from yum repo)
- autoconf
- automake
- gcc
- zlib-devel
- openssl-devel
- cmake

When I run "mvn package -X -e -Pdist,native,docs -Dskiptests -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none" in the hadoop src directory, I get the following error messages:

```
...
...


The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [exec] -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
     [exec] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
     [exec] CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
     [exec] JAVA_HOME=, JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=/usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
     [exec] JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/java/latest/include, JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2=/usr/java/latest/include/linux
     [exec] Located all JNI components successfully.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.019 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.811 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  2.167 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.186 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  2.436 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [ 16.710 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [ 14.504 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [ 51.894 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  1.960 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [  6.005 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:39 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T00:47:38+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 75M/202M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 4:129 in /dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 4:129 in /dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 4:129 in /dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: /dev/shm/hadoop-2.4.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml:4: exec returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Any idea?